# Have a detailed look at apache server incoming request

Tags: apache

I was wondering is their a way to have a detailed look at what requests are coming on my `apache server`. I mean like the `tkt101` server in interactive mode.

Comment: What is tkt101? Could you give a reference?

Comment: tkt101 is a dedicated server to receive request's from a tkt device. tkt devices are GPS tracking device. This all works on OpenGTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not know the tkt101 server, I cannot answer precisely. You probably have already researched Apaches `CustomLog` directive. If you want more, you might try [modsecurity](https://modsecurity.org/) which offers advanced features for [traffic logging](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mod-security/index.php?title=Reference_Manual#HTTP_Traffic_Logging)